# Spring boot 2.0.0 actuator endpoints not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have created a sample application with spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE and added below dependencies. I have also configured Jersey for some application specific endpoint.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Also added the following properties in the application properties to expose the actuator endpoints-

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=threaddump, env, configprops
```

And its working as expected.

Then, once I tried to add `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency in the POM, ***the actuators endpoints stop working***. I don't see any exception and see the `/actuator` endpoint has been mapped to the logs. Any idea? TIA

Comment: you claim you've found a solution to this issue in  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12368 - could you share that as an answer?